# how do i get the data from the php class in my jquery code

Tags: php, jquery

I have php calss called `class SpecialSCMembers extends SpecialPagePlugin` This class return data in HTMl format and i want when user click on "Membership Directory" tab this page load bellow the "Membership Directory" tab. my tab are look like "Account|Profile|Sc Member|Membership Update|Membership Directory"

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly it is you want? Right now, I can only guess this might be useful: http://api.jquery.com/load/ or some kind of Ajax equivalent. edit: Do you want the content to load dynamically or do you want the page to refresh with new content?

Comment: Either include the classes output as content of the tab whilst keeing it hidden when you generate the html containing the tab. Then you already _have_ the html inside the tab and just have to make it visible. Or you have to use an ajax call when the tab is chosen and fetch the classes output. When the ajax request is successful you can add the resuting html markup to the DOM tree as content of the tab.

Comment: I have the page callded http://url/special:scmemer which gives me data i want this page load into my membership directory page. This page in my deki/plugins/special_page/special_scmembers/special_scmembers.php

Comment: Since you've tagged this question with jQuery, I'm assuming you would be open to using it. I would recommend that you take a look at http://api.jquery.com/load or http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and add an `onClick` listener to the Navigation Tabs which would then trigger a function which `loads` the HTML from the external file by passing the page using Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax to load the content of the HTML page into your tab. You can send HTML from the php class, and then set the innerHTML of a DIV to the html code using Javascript when your Ajax request returns.